# Almacenar SELECT en Array Bidimensional PHP / JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, array, select

he estado realizando esta consulta, en la cual hago dos consultas a dos tablas, para tomar en una los datos del Estudiante y en la Otra los modulos que cursa.

Lo que necesito es que me genere un arreglo, donde por cada estudiante me almacene los modulos y me los genere en un JSON. Hasta ahora, sin exito a la hora de querer insertar los Modulos y Costo por estudiante juntos.

Observe en el JSON que adjunto me muestra todos, pero me duplica los estudiantes con sus distintos modulos. Necesito que todos los modulos queden en un solo Array de estudiante.

```
<?php

// CONECTA A LA BASE DE DATOS
function connectDB(){
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "urbe_ajax";


try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$bd;charset=UTF8", $user, $pass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $conexion;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
// DESCONECTA A LA BASE DE DATOS
function disconnectDB(){

$conexion = null;

}

function getEstudiantes(){
$conexion = connectDB();

//Prapara la Consulta SQL
if (!($consulta  = $conexion->prepare("
SELECT * 
FROM `estudiantes`  
ORDER BY `estudiantes`.`id` ASC"))){
    echo "Fallo la Preparación";} 

if (!($consulta2  = $conexion->prepare("
SELECT estudiantes.*, diplomado.id, diplomado.id_estudiante, diplomado.modulo, diplomado.costo 
FROM `estudiantes` 
INNER JOIN `diplomado` 
ON id_estudiante = estudiantes.id 
ORDER BY `diplomado`.`id_estudiante` ASC"))){
    echo "Fallo la Preparación";} 

//Ejecuta la Consulta SQL
if (!($consulta->execute())) {
    echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
} 

if (!($consulta2->execute())) {
    echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
} 

$i = 0;
//Devuelte todos los resultados de la Consulta SQL
foreach ($a = $consulta->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
// var_dump($a[$key]['id']);
$b = $a[$key]['id'];
    foreach ($c = $consulta2->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        if($c[$key][$b] = $b){

            $arr[$i] = array( 'id' =>$c[$key]['cedula'],  
                'nombre' => $c[$key]['nombre'],  
                'fecha' => $c[$key]['fecha_nac'],  
                    array(
                        'modulo' => $c[$key]['modulo'], 
                        'costo' => $c[$key]['costo']
                    )
                ); 
            $i++; 
            }; 
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; 
            var_dump($arr); 
            echo "</pre>";   

    $json = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $archivo = 'ESTUDIANTES.json';
    file_put_contents($archivo, $json);

    // print_r($json);

}
```

//JSON GENERADO

```
[
{
    "id": "V23749282",
    "nombre": "JHON ESAA",
    "fecha": "1991-01-23",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "LOTTT: CALCULO SALARIAL",
        "costo": "200"
    }
},
{
    "id": "V23749282",
    "nombre": "JHON ESAA",
    "fecha": "1991-01-23",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "AJAX & JSON",
        "costo": "500"
    }
},
{
    "id": "V23749282",
    "nombre": "JHON ESAA",
    "fecha": "1991-01-23",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "MARKETING Y REDES",
        "costo": "300"
    }
},
{
    "id": "18064185",
    "nombre": "GERALDINE ARNAIZ",
    "fecha": "1987-11-11",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "LOTTT: CALCULO SALARIAL",
        "costo": "200"
    }
},
{
    "id": "18064185",
    "nombre": "GERALDINE ARNAIZ",
    "fecha": "1987-11-11",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "TRAMITE DE ADUANA",
        "costo": "800"
    }
},
{
    "id": "18064185",
    "nombre": "GERALDINE ARNAIZ",
    "fecha": "1987-11-11",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "MARKETING Y REDES",
        "costo": "300"
    }
},
{
    "id": "v26333448",
    "nombre": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "fecha": "1997-02-26",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "TRAMITE DE ADUANA",
        "costo": "800"
    }
},
{
    "id": "v26333448",
    "nombre": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "fecha": "1997-02-26",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "COMERCIO EXTERNO",
        "costo": "600"
    }
},
{
    "id": "v26333448",
    "nombre": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "fecha": "1997-02-26",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "AJAX & JSON",
        "costo": "500"
    }
}
]
```

//JSON QUE NECESITO MOSTRAR

```
[
{
    "id": "V23749282",
    "nombre": "JHON ESAA",
    "fecha": "1991-01-23",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "LOTTT: CALCULO SALARIAL",
        "costo": "200"
    },
    "2": {
        "modulo": "AJAX & JSON",
        "costo": "500"
    },
    "3": {
        "modulo": "AJAX & JSON",
        "costo": "500"
    }
},
{
    "id": "18064185",
    "nombre": "GERALDINE ARNAIZ",
    "fecha": "1987-11-11",
    "0": {
        "modulo": "LOTTT: CALCULO SALARIAL",
        "costo": "200"
    },
    "1": {
        "modulo": "TRAMITE DE ADUANA",
        "costo": "800"
    },
    "3": {
        "modulo": "MARKETING Y REDES",
        "costo": "300"
    }
}
]
```

EDIT>CAMBIE EL CODIGO:

```
function getEstudiantes(){
$conexion = connectDB();

//Prapara la Consulta SQL
// if (!($consulta  = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `estudiantes`  ORDER BY `estudiantes`.`id` ASC"))){
//     echo "Fallo la Preparación";} 

if (!($consulta2  = $conexion->prepare("SELECT estudiantes.*, diplomado.id, diplomado.id_estudiante, diplomado.modulo, diplomado.costo FROM `estudiantes` INNER JOIN `diplomado` ON id_estudiante = estudiantes.id ORDER BY `diplomado`.`id_estudiante` ASC"))){
    echo "Fallo la Preparación";}

if (!($consulta2->execute())) {
    echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
} 
$datos = $consulta2->fetchAll();

//Ejecuta la Consulta SQL
// if (!($consulta->execute())) {
//     echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
// } 



$i = 0;
//Devuelve todos los resultados de la Consulta SQL

    while ($i <= count($datos)-1) {
        var_dump($datos[$i]['id_estudiante']); 
        echo '<hr>';
    foreach ($datos as $value) { 
        if($value['id_estudiante'] == $i) {

            echo "<pre>"; 
                var_dump($value['id_estudiante']);
                var_dump($value['nombre']);
                var_dump($value['modulo']);

                $arr[$i] = array( 'cedula' =>$value['cedula'],  
                    'nombre' => $value['nombre'],  
                    'fecha' => $value['fecha_nac']
                    ); 
            echo "</pre>";    
            array_push($arr[$i], array(
                'modulo' => $value['modulo'], 
                'costo' => $value['costo']
                   )
               );
        };            
    };
        $i++;
    }         


echo "<pre>"; 
    var_dump($arr); 
echo "</pre>";  
}
```

Tengo esto, y aun no doy. El Push dentro del IF, me reemplaza el valor anterior, no me lo matiente, pero si lo traslado al FOREACH, me agrega todos los modulos y costos que haya (El problema es que me los agrega todos, no solo los que pertenecen a ese ESTUDIANTE).

Comment: El problema es que no necesitas dos consultas. Con la segunda debería traerte todos los datos. Tampoco necesitas marear tanto los datos en PDO. Con que hagas esto: `$arrDatos=$consulta2->fetchAll();` ¡ya tienes un array con los datos!. Ahora, sólo lo conviertes a JSON con: `$json = json_encode($arrDatos, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`  Si el JSON no te queda como esperas entonces tienes que trabajar los resultados para darle al JSON al orden que deseas. El hecho es que tu código tiene demasiado *código basura* (lo digo con respeto)... o sea, demasiado código innecesario.

Comment: Si, en la medida en que he ido buscando las maneras, he ensuciado mucho el codigo. El punto es que no he dado con la forma de recorrerlos y guardar los valores en sus respectivos lugares.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO: ESTO ME DEVUELVE JUSTO LO QUE BUSCABA.

```
function getEstudiantes(){
$conexion = connectDB();

//Prapara la Consulta SQL
// if (!($consulta  = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `estudiantes`  ORDER BY `estudiantes`.`id` ASC"))){
//     echo "Fallo la Preparación";} 

if (!($consulta2  = $conexion->prepare("SELECT estudiantes.*, diplomado.id, diplomado.id_estudiante, diplomado.modulo, diplomado.costo FROM `estudiantes` INNER JOIN `diplomado` ON id_estudiante = estudiantes.id ORDER BY `diplomado`.`id_estudiante` ASC"))){
    echo "Fallo la Preparación";}

//Ejecuta la Consulta SQL
if (!($consulta2->execute())) {
    echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
} 

//Guarda el arreglo de la Consulta SQL en una variable
$datos = $consulta2->fetchAll();



$i = 0; //Contador
$result = []; //Arreglo vacio donde iran los resultados

//Recorre el Arreglo y Guarda en una variable los datos recogidos
    while ($i <= count($datos)-1) {
        var_dump($datos[$i]['id_estudiante']); 
        echo '<hr>';
    foreach ($datos as $value) { 
        if($value['id_estudiante'] == $i) {

            echo "<pre>"; 
                var_dump($value['id_estudiante']);
                var_dump($value['nombre']);
                var_dump($value['modulo']);

                $arr[$i] = array( 'cedula' =>$value['cedula'],  
                    'nombre' => $value['nombre'],  
                    'fecha' => $value['fecha_nac']
                    ); 
            echo "</pre>";  
            $result += $arr;
            array_push($result[$i], array(
                'modulo' => $value['modulo'], 
                'costo' => $value['costo']
                   )
               );
        };            
    };
        $i++;
    }         


echo "<pre>"; 
    var_dump($result); 
echo "</pre>";  

    $json = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $archivo = 'ESTUDIANTES.json';
    file_put_contents($archivo, $json);

    // print_r($json);

}
```